# How to Merge Multiple Files from Multiple folders using Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

The code below works by merging multiple files from different directories to create a single output file. The expected output is correct but the way the arguments are passed to the `%FileName%` are not correct.

Sample log from CMD:

> ```
> C:\VP\TEST>type "C:\VP\APC\832I\810 - Copy.txt"  1>>"C:\VP\MACS_IN_PROCESS\WI832MCS.dat"
> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> C:\VP\TEST>move "C:\VP\APC\832I\810 - Copy.txt" "C:\VP\MACS_IN_ARCHIVE\810 - Copy.txt"
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

Code of batch file:

```
@echo on
::This ensures the parameters are resolved prior to the internal variable
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SetLocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

rem Get current date and time as local time.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\Find.exe "."') do set dt=%%a

rem Reformat the date and time strong to wanted format.
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "TimeStamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

rem Define name of the list file containing current date and time in name.
set "APC810_ListFile=APC810_FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"
set "APC832_ListFile=APC832_FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"
set "APC846_ListFile=APC846_FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"
set "APC855_ListFile=APC855_FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"
set "APC856_ListFile=APC856_FLIST_%TimeStamp%.lst"

rem Create file list
cd /D "C:\VP\APC\810I"
dir *.txt /A:-D /B /O:D >"C:\VP\TEST\%APC810_ListFile%"

cd /D "C:\VP\APC\832I"
dir *.txt /A:-D /B /O:D >"C:\VP\TEST\%APC832_ListFile%"

rem  ====================== APC 810 ======================
rem Process each file in the list file.
cd /D "C:\VP\TEST"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ( %APC810_ListFile% ) do call :Process810 "%%F"


rem  ====================== APC 832 ======================
rem Process each file in the list file.
cd /D "C:\VP\TEST"
for /F "delims=" %%F in ( %APC832_ListFile% ) do call :Process832 "%%F"

rem Exit batch file.
endlocal
goto :EOF


:Process810
set "FileName=%~1"
type "C:\VP\APC\810I\%FileName%" >>"C:\VP\MACS_IN_PROCESS\I810MCS.dat"
move "C:\VP\APC\810I\%FileName%" "C:\VP\MACS_IN_ARCHIVE\%FileName%"

:Process832
set "FileName=%~1"
type "C:\VP\APC\832I\%FileName%" >>"C:\VP\MACS_IN_PROCESS\WI832MCS.dat"
move "C:\VP\APC\832I\%FileName%" "C:\VP\MACS_IN_ARCHIVE\%FileName%"
```

Comment: You need to specify precisely what you want and what you actually get! Otherwise this question is useless to other users and might therefore become closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but your post does not specify the problem, you state that your output is correct but that passed arguments are not. *(surely if you're passing incorrect arguments the results would be incorrect too)*

Here is a very quick re-write, it is untested and may contain errors.

```bat
@Echo Off

For /F "EOL=L" %%a In ('WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime') Do For %%b In (%%a
) Do Set "dt=%%~nb"
Set "Stamp=%dt:~,4%-%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%_%dt:~8,2%-%dt:~10,2%-%dt:~12,2%"

For %%a In (10 32 46 55 56) Do (
    Dir/B/A-D/OD "C:\VP\APC\8%%aI\*.txt">"C:\VP\TEST\APC8%%a_FLIST_%Stamp%.lst"
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%b In ("C:\VP\TEST\APC8%%a_FLIST_%Stamp%.lst"
    ) Do (Type "%%b">>"C:\VP\MACS_IN_PROCESS\I8%%aMCS.dat"
        Move "%%b" "C:\VP\MACS_IN_ARCHIVE"))
```

*…try it and see if it helps*.